# Saving a decimal number to a cell gives unwanted result

Tags: excel, vba

I read a double from one sheet, store it in a Double variable and write this variable as a .Value2 in another sheet. The used decimal separator in excel and system is "," comma. When the number has less than 3 digits after the decimal separator the result in the destination sheet is ok. If there are three digits the problem shows up. The destination sheet does not have any 
cells formatting.

Examples:

```
120 -> 120 OK
12,2 -> 12,2 OK
1,22 -> 1,22 OK
120,233 -> 120 233 Bad
```

This is how I save the value:

```
Let value = ws.Range(cellAddress).Offset(27, colOffset).value

Set element = New DailyTotal
element.Init name, EIC, value
```

And this is how I write it to the destination:

```
ws.Cells(targetRow, targetCol).Value2 = el.value
```

Comment: Please show your code.  There are numerous ways to go about this and to go through that explanation exercise would be subjective leading to closure of your post; the goal is to provide an objective answer to your particular issue.

Comment: Code added. The value variable is a object property.

Comment: Let value.  What is the type of value.  Also, the .value method of excel is not guaranteed to return a number

Comment: Would help to also show the class code for `DailyTotal`

Comment: `Dim val as double` then `val = ws.Range(cellAddress).Offset(27, colOffset).value` should pull the number, unless there is an error where the value is non-numeric... in regard to ensuring a value is there, use `IsNumber()` to check (returns boolean)

Comment: In general, your post is relatively cryptic, where the new info we get leads to more questions... would you please try to provide some more context around what is being presented, while presenting with adequate transparency (it is understood that some items may not be appropriate for a public forum, however we need enough to work with).

Comment: Problem solved. The DailyTotal Get value property was set as string, though the field f_value which this property returns is set to double. After changing the property type to double it behaves correctly.